# Linux - bridging eth0 and at0 with brctl

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge, ad-hoc-network

The problem is as follows:
I have a router running a DHCP server connected (with a cable) to a computer with a wireless card. I want to create and ad-hoc network using airbase-ng then bridge it to eth0 (I know this doesn't make much sense, it's meant to be an exercise) so that anyone who connects to the ad-hoc network:

1) can access the outside world through the computer running the network
2) gets an IP address from the DHCP server the router is running

I tried:

```
brctl addbr Bridge
brctl addif eth0
brctl addif at0
```

But I'm not sure what to do next (to start Bridge), also adding eth0 to Bridge for some reason makes it not work, even if I configure it again after adding (`dhclient eth0`).

This is probably a noob question, but I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you just did was create a new network interface called `Bridge` which has `eth0` and `at0` junctioned into it.  The interface named `Bridge` should show up in `ifconfig`.

So doing anything to `eth0` or `at0` individually afterward (except getting `at0` on/off a wireless network) doesn't make sense.  They are part of the bridge.

Try `dhclient -v Bridge` and see if `Bridge` can get an IP from your DHCP server.

Comment: My `dhclient` never heard of a -v option, but I just did `dhclient Bridge` and it worked like a charm - thanks :).